# Symfony2: Propel uniqueness validator

Tags: forms, symfony, propel

I want to use the UniqueObject validator with Symfony2 and Propel (as explained on http://propelorm.org/Propel/cookbook/symfony2/mastering-symfony2-forms-with-propel.html).

This is working fine with a single object, with a collection of objects then the validator is not used on each object.

I did it in debug mode and noticed the same behavior: the class UniqueObjectValidator is even not used when updating a collection.

Any idea how to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution => I did not set the cascading validation properly